# How to delete hidden checkbox in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

How can I delete the checked checkbox of previous pages which are not visible?

Please suggest some easy and explainable solution according to my code.
When I select multiple check boxes on different pages, the check boxes do remain selected properly - the problem is that when I delete the checkboxes, it only sends the values of the currently showing page.

For example, if I have 5 pages of data, and I select 2 checkboxes from each page (in total 10), only the values of 2 of the checkboxes get passed on.

```js
<script>  
  
   
    
    
    //Delete conformation message
    /***************************/
    

    
    //SelectAll checkBox
    /****************************/
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        
        var table= $('#testtable').DataTable({
            autoWidth: true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "deferRender": true,
             
            order: [[ 1, "asc" ]]
        });
    $('#checkall').click(function(){
         var checked = this.checked;

        table.column(0).nodes().to$().each(function(index) {

      if (checked) {

            $(this).find('.delete_checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');

          } 
          else {

              $(this).find('.delete_checkbox').removeProp('checked');

              }

         });

       table.draw();
    });
    /********************************/
        
    
    //Select indivisual checkBox
    /*******************************/
    $('.delete_checkbox').click(function(){
         

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('removeRow');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('removeRow');
        }
    });
    /*******************************/
    


    //Deletion of Data
       /***********************************/
        $('#delete_all').click(function(){    
             
        var checkbox = $('.delete_checkbox:checked');
        
        
        if(checkbox.length > 0)
        {  
            var result=confirm("Are you sure");
            if(result==true)
            {
                var checkbox_valu = [];
            $(checkbox).each(function(){
                checkbox_valu.push($(this).val());
            });

            $.ajax({
                url:"delete.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{checkbox_id:checkbox_valu},
                success:function()
                {
                    $('.removeRow').fadeOut(1500);
                    location.reload(true)

                }
            });
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

            
        }
        
        else
        {
            alert("Select atleast one records");
        }
    });
      /******************************************/
 
    
    




    

});

  
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.removeRow
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Delete Multiple Records using PHP Ajax with Animated Effect</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

   

        
    </head>  
    <body >  
        <div class="container">  
            <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h3 align="center">Delete Multiple Records using PHP Ajax with Animated Effect</h3><br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" autocomplete="off"/>
                                <button type="button"  id="delete_all" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button> 
                    <table id ="testtable" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class='no-sort' width="10%">
                              
                                
                                                          
                                
                            </th>
                            <th width="20%">Name</th>
                            <th width="38%">Address</th>
                            <th width="7%">Gender</th>
                            <th width="25%">Designation</th>
                            <th width="5%">Age</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        foreach($result as $row)
                        {
                            echo '
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="delete_checkbox" value="'.$row["id"].'" />
                                </td>
                                <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["designation"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>
                            </tr>
                            ';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html> strong text
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what do you mean. Maybe some example? Images of steps? Results? Live example? If they are being deleted, why to show them and send their values?

Comment: For example, if I have 5 pages of data, and I select 2 checkboxes from each page (in total 10), if i click delete button  then it only delete the current page data("data of the row of which checked checkbox are visible") . it will not delete the data of other pages ("because the checkhed checkbox of other pages are not visible")

Comment: You can try to duplicate your checkboxes to hidden inputs when page is being switched or (more complicated, as it needs to change other styles as well) to switch `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`

Comment: flash thusder ("var checkbox = $('.delete_checkbox:checked');") this code only contain the value on visible checked checkbox. How can i store the value of hidden  checkbox which are not on current page

Comment: please help me ,i am new to web development

Comment: I will, but in few hours got to go now.

Comment: There is nothing about pagination in your code, how do you paginate it?

Comment: thanks for your help, problem resolve now